# Looking for a dropwizard example

Tags: dropwizard

Looking for a dropwizard example I found:

https://github.com/codahale/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-example

But I am interested in a more complete example with at least:

1. a 1:n relationship like customer - account
2. a html gui represenation at least with forms
3. full crud support for xml

2 out of three would be a start and would earn "accepted" by me.

Comment: What did *you* try to earn answers to this question?

Comment: I am in the process of preparing an answer myself since I think there is need for it. If nobody else answers I'll present one.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No - i never worked with dropwizard due to this.Given the high amount of views of this question i am gladed i asked, though.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, Wolfgang :-)

Answer (score 19):

**Take a look at some of my [Dropwzard projects](https://github.com/gary-rowe)**

In particular the [MultiBit Merchant](https://github.com/gary-rowe/MultiBitMerchant/wiki/Getting-started-for-developers) projects (Admin, Store and Platform) will provide you with a wealth of demonstration code that shows how to get stuff done in Dropwizard. There is also an example of OpenID with Dropwizard that should provide a good launch point for a new application.

They are all FOSS under the MIT license.

Answer (score 7):

Wolfgang,

here is an [example Dropwizard application](https://bitbucket.org/dnoranovich/dropwizard-getting-started) where Authentication, Configuration and database access using Hibernate are used.

The application is discussed in several tutorials:

- [First Steps](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2015/01/getting-started-with-dropwizard-first.html)
- [Authentication, Configuration and HTTPS](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2015/02/getting-started-with-dropwizard.html)
- [Connecting to a Database using Hibernate](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2015/11/getting-started-with-dropwizard.html)
- [Connecting to external REST Web-services using Jersey Client](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2015/12/getting-started-with-dropwizard.html)

And [here](https://bitbucket.org/dnoranovich/dropbookmarks) is another example, where one can store bookmarks for authenticated users and access data via REST API.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a nice example as well: https://github.com/spinscale/dropwizard-blog-sample

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an example in my [Dropwizard XML Bundle](https://github.com/yunspace/dropwizard-xml) project:

https://github.com/yunspace/dropwizard-xml/tree/master/dropwizard-xml-example

It's probably the closest to what you are looking for. It has:

- 1:N relationship between Pirates and Ships, stored in a H2 db.
- Full CRUD support for XML using custom JacksonMessageBodyProvider with validation.

Adding HTML gui via Freemarker or Mustache templates should be pretty trivial and is covered in the standard docs.

Answer (score 2):

A good example who want dropwizard with authentication.

Dropwizard: Authentication, Configuration and HTTPS
https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-dropwizard-0

Answer (score 0):

You can try this project from Github.

Dropwizard: CRUD operation, HTML views, Healthcheck

https://github.com/HoldInArms/dropwizard-mssql-crud-example

Comment: Good example but the above code seems to use an older version of dropwizard. Same code ported to Mysql with 1.0.5 dropwizard version - https://github.com/rahulsh1/dropwizard-mysql-crud-example

Answer (score -2):

**follow below step.**

1. Add dependencies in pom file

   ```
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
       <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
       <version>0.6.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create configuration class

   ```
   import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Configuration;
   public class BlogConfiguration extends Configuration{

    }
   ```
3. Create Service class

   ```
      import com.yammer.dropwizard.Service;
      import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Bootstrap;
      import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Environment;

      public class BlogService extends Service<BlogConfiguration> {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      new BlogService().run(new String[] { "server",
      "C:\\LocalEnv\\Workspace\\dropwizarddemo\\configuration.yml" });
       }

       @Override
      public void initialize(Bootstrap<BlogConfiguration> bootstrap) {
      bootstrap.setName("blog");
      }

      @Override
       public void run(BlogConfiguration configuration, 
       Environment    environment) throws Exception {
       environment.addResource(new IndexResource());
       }

     }
   ```

Note: put below configuration.yml file in current directory

```
       # HTTP-specific options.
       http:

       # The port on which the HTTP server listens for service requests.
       port: 8079

       # The port on which the HTTP server listens for administrative
       # requests.
       adminPort: 8179

      # Maximum number of threads.
      maxThreads: 100

      # Minimum number of thread to keep alive.
      minThreads: 10
```

4. Write Index resources.

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Arrays;
     import java.util.List;
     import javax.ws.rs.GET;
     import javax.ws.rs.Path;
     import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
     import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


    import com.yammer.metrics.annotation.Timed;

    @Path("/")
    public class IndexResource {

   @GET
   @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Timed
   public List<Blog> index() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Blog("for Java Developers",
   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345693/looking-for-a-dropwizard-
    example”));
   }


   @Path("/service")


   @GET
   @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Timed
   public List<Users> users() {
    List<Users> list = new ArrayList<Users>();
    list.add(new Users(25,"Sambhu","SA"));
    list.add(new Users(35,"Amit","VP"));
    list.add(new Users(45,"Sanket","AVP"));


    return list;
    }


  }
```

5. Write POJO for Blog and Users like

   ```
    public class Users {


    Integer id;
    String name;
    String designation;

    public Users(Integer id, String name, String desination){
   this.id=id;
   this.name=name;
   this.designation=desination;
   }

   public Integer getId() {
   return id;
   }
   public void setId(Integer id) {
   this.id = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
   return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
   }
   public String getDesignation() {
   return designation;
   }
   public void setDesignation(String designation) {
   this.designation = designation;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
   return "Users [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", designation="
           + designation + "]";
   }
   ```
6. Run BlogService which will start the Jetty server and hit the localhost with port such as 
          http://localhost:8079/