# Quick RESTful services straight out of the database

Tags: database, rest

I am investigating ways to quickly produce RESTful services without much coding.

I have looked into Google Feed Server already

Our data lives in PostgreSQL mostly.

Does anyone have any experience with any other good tools?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345693/looking-for-a-dropwizard-example is not answered yet and I am working on a solution for Java/Jersey you might want to contact me personally to check whether your database would be a good example. You can reach me via my companies feedback form.

Answer (score 2):

If you want do it in Java, then Netbeans (in combination with JAX-RS and glassfish) is a pretty good solution. They have a wizard that generates RESTful end-points starting from a DB schema. They also have good tutorials for that on their web site.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to quickly build CRUD functionality over a RESTful API might be to use the following bundle for Symfony 2 (in PHP):

```
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle
```

It will require some configuration and basic functionality using Doctrine, but should be relatively fast to build.