# Android: Get the list of downloadable files from a specific URL

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development, and I have a problem.
I would like to create an app where we can listen/stream MP3's from a server.
I know how to stream an MP3, but I would like to know how to have the list of every MP3 that can be streamed on my server. Do you see what I mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a RESTful API for this. I suggest you try DropWizard.

Besically you will  create an endpoint like www.myserver.com/mp3s

When that URL is called you can return in JSON (or XML or whatever you decide to use) the list of files

There are a bunch of DropWizard projects on GitHub that you can use a reference, see this SO question for some links [Looking for a dropwizard example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345693/looking-for-a-dropwizard-example)